# CNOT circuit synthesis with Gauss elimination. Explanation and beyond?

Tags: gate-synthesis, matrix-representation

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0302002) introduces to the synthesis of a (optimal) circuit of CNOTs only; starting from a parity map encoded into a matrix.

It is based on *Gaussian Elimination*.

This is an important result, which find some revisits to make it work for topology constrained circuits.

For example, https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00633 presents a *Gauss-Steiner* combination to be compliant with the topology.

Authors state that for the synthesis there is some freedom of choice and they greedily choose one that maximise the parallelism:

> Note that in this phase, we have **some** freedom to choose which row operations to perform. Here we have taken a greedy strategy for maximising the number of row operations that can be done in parallel.

I would like to understand better such a method.
What observation can be made? E.g. What is the relation between the diagonal and the CNOTs? What freedom do we have when selecting a row/operation to synthesise?